# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

As we have entered public beta, it will soon become apparent that we need more moderator attention than can be given by the SE mods that have accounts here.  We already have two users who have access to the moderator tools, and possibly one or two more soon, which helps quite a bit. But, we will need people with true moderator power. At this point, they are appointed, not elected, but we can make the SE team's work easier if we do the ground work for them by gauging interest in such a post. So, on to the question:

Who is interested in becoming a [moderator pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) on this site? Please post your interest in the answers below, and be sure to read [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) before you commit. Also, please have a valid email address that you check regularly at which the SE team may contact you.

As a matter of course, you can nominate another person to the post, but be prepared for the possibility of them declining the post.

(This is a precursor to question 6 of the [7 Essential Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).)

Comment: I wonder how much time such a job would take...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I have no idea. Yoda knows, though.

Comment: @Sjoerd it really depends on the moderator. Some people are super-dedicated to their site (I spend a ton of time moderating Physics), some people are pretty laid back and only really show up when they are called upon (e.g. by flags). Moderating a beta site tends to require more of the former crowd. It definitely does take a big chunk out of your capacity to just ask and answer questions, unless you try very hard not to let it.

Answer (score 15):

If there is a need, I will step up.  Referencing StackOverflow:

1. [I am here quite a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5845436/618728)
2. I had a flag weight of 750, and have the Marshal, Copy Editor, and Sportsman badges.
3. I don't think anyone hates me (yet?), and I don't hate anyone.

Comment: I just learned *flag weight* is gone...

Comment: @Sjoerd you're right.

Comment: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148/57

Comment: Well, I voted for you, but am not sure whether it would be healthy for you

Comment: Oh noes! We're losing one of our top contributors to moderator hell? Is this some sort of penance for over achieving? Next you'll tell me that Leonid is running for mod :P j/k... :)

Comment: it would be nice to know who and where you are.

Comment: @Rolf Ok, let me come clean: Mr.Wizard is actually an alias of mine... I'm glad I can finally confess.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries No, I'm Spatac... I mean, Mr.Wizard!

Comment: @R.M I'm Mr.W, and so's my wife!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I must confess, that I too am a member of the Mr.Wizard collective. Even with the members of the collective, it has been difficult maintaining the grueling posting schedule that a poster of Mr.Wizard's caliber must maintain. It is good to finally be out in the open, and, hopefully, we all can get the credit we deserve.

Comment: @rcollyer I feel relieved now that we spilled our beans.

Comment: LOL! Y'all bring tears to my eyes.  Rolf, I rather value my anonymity if only for the hilarious comments above that it allows.  Honestly I am just a bloke with a sleep disorder and there is not much else to tell, but my name is Paul and I live in Oregon, USA if that comforts you.

Answer (score 14):

I'm willing to do a bit of mod work for mma.SE; I think having actively participated for more than a year on various other SE sites (e.g. math.SE) has given me a good feel for SE's theory of moderation, and I think I am up to the task of upholding the responsibilities expected of a *pro tempore* moderator, if chosen to be one.

Answer (score 14):

If the community is willing to deal with my ongoing attempt to graduate this year, I am willing to help moderate.

As to my experience, I used to moderate [another site](http://www.omninerd.com/), where prior to a change in format, I reviewed any news or articles posted. Additionally, I am one of the top answerers on SO in the Mathematica tag, and have been seen regularly editing the content there. Also, as most of you are well aware, I have been involved intimately with the launch of this site, and have been trying to keep us moving towards our ultimate goal: graduation into a fully-fledged SE site.

**Edit**: Thank you all for voting for me, but I must withdraw myself from consideration. My timeline for completion just became very tight. Maybe I'll throw my hat in the ring when the permanent mods are elected, but until then, I cannot afford the extra time.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure whether four moderators would be acceptable, but if so, I would like to offer my services as well. This in addition to, and expressly not in competition with, those already offered by rcollyer, Mr.wizard and J.M.

I'm a long time user of Mathematica (about 20 years). I participated in the mathgroup for several years and for almost a year in the Mathematica tag of SO. I am conveniently located in the WET (GMT+1) time zone, which would improve the mod group's coverage of the 24 hr day.