# Where is the record of the agreement referred to here?

Tags: discussion

"don't use the platform name as tag unless you are sure the platform plays a role" EDIT: "If you own different platforms you can do the experimentation wrt system specificity yourself; if not, wait until community members have checked this" https://archive.is/GkVrc#selection-1219.5-1219.86

"This was community consensus, agreed upon" https://archive.is/GkVrc#selection-1789.36-1789.77

Link(s) please. "In my memory" need not apply.

Comment: Lemme tell you now, so you don't get blindsided: your attitude thus far is going to make potential helpers way less likely to assist you, even though your questions might be legitimate. We are spending our time here as *volunteers*, not getting paid anything, and we like it if askers meet us halfway and try to be less hostile. Now, wouldn't *that* be nice?

Comment: I have faith that the particpants here are not as petty as you imply.

Comment: As you say. I'm just saying what frequently happens in situations like these so you won't be surprised by any future developments; this isn't the first time a user has rubbed a community wrongly.

Comment: I should also say: you sure have a very peculiar way of treating people you say you have faith in.

Comment: why is this such a big deal? either way? some serious _drama_ going on... let me get this straight, this is all over the use of a particular _tag?_ ie WPC?

Answer (score 15):

[QFT](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/q/f/What-Is-QFT.htm):

> Lemme tell you now, so you don't get blindsided: your attitude thus far is going to make potential helpers way less likely to assist you, even though your questions might be legitimate. We are spending our time here as *volunteers*, not getting paid anything, and we like it if askers meet us halfway and try to be less hostile. Now, wouldn't *that* be nice?  –  Guess who it is.♦

As an established member of our community, valued long-time contributor, and former [moderator pro tempore](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/154/121), [Sjoerd](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) is well within his right to write in an authoritative tone when addressing a new user regarding site guidelines, **from his memory** or otherwise.  "Guess who it is" (J.M.) is an *active, community-elected moderator* (as am I) and is further entitled to speak authoritatively.  If **we** privately arrived at a site policy it is no less valid that one established by public Meta Q&A consensus.  I am genuinely sorry if this rubs you the wrong way but I feel we are well within *the will of the people* in what we do.

My memory is not as complete as I wish so I cannot directly support J.M.'s statement that "this was community consensus" but my point is that it really doesn't matter.

I am *not* saying that site policy is written is stone.  That's a major part of what this Meta site is about: developing and improving policy, which is why I thanked you for your question about WPC.  Questioning site policy, wording, etc. can be *helpful* and I have attempted to be responsive to you regarding it.  However as noted repeatedly by others your attitude comes off as abrasive; if you want your inquires to be received and respected you need to work to improve that.

Comment: "*If we privately arrived at a site policy it is no less valid that one established by public Meta Q&A consensus.*" If you did privately arrive at this site policy, then way not just say so rather than pontificate about your authority? And why not update the docs http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/tagging . "*I am not saying that site policy is written is stone.*" I wonder if you are saying it is not written at all. In which case how do you expect people to know to follow it?

Comment: SFAICT, only SE employees can edit the help pages. If you want to complain about doc relevance, @Chris, you might want to take it to meta.SE…

Comment: @ChrisJJ I don't know, how you interpreted the help pages to your ends. E.g. *If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. For example, the meaning of the tag `[subjective]` is, itself, subjective; the same is true for tags like `[best-practices]` and `[beginner]`. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? Use only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective definition.* Your `wpc` tag clearly means something different to the locals, than it does to you.

Comment: @ChrisJJ (1) As I said I don't remember the origin of every practice.  (2) My intent is not to pontificate about my authority; rather it *seems* like you are unhappy that there *is* any authority here; "only if it is written in /help is it valid" is the underlying tone, and I'm telling you that is simply not the way it works here. (3) Some policy is written, some isn't.  You are not expected to magically know an unwritten policy, you are only expected to believe there is one if community moderators tell you there is one.  (continued)

Comment: I *know* you have received conflicting statements from some users and I am sorry; I am *trying* to remedy this by answering your questions and making corrections where I can.  However you must be willing to accept that not everything is written, not everything *is* presently defined clearly, and not everything that *is* written is going to perfectly agree.  As noted above many of these pages are not directly editable so there is only so much we can do.